# Creating a Step Object for Automation in ExactTarget .Net API

Tags: marketing-cloud

This code issues an error in .Net, saying "***Step is not defined***".

```
var steps = new Step[1];
```

**Can you confirm that this is true or false?  This is the .Net code to create a Step object for an Automation using the API.**

This issue is referenced as a part of creating an Automation Object in the API https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api/

Comment: Did this answer get you where you needed to be?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the example was referencing the incorrect object names. Step should actually be AutomationTask.  The example of the page you referenced is now updated with the correct names.